# context.Authentication.User is Null in Owin WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, azure-active-directory, owin

I have a web api that receives requests from multiple clients and authenticates them via an Azure Active Directory tokens.

**Existing apps**

Existing clients are able to successfully authenticate with the API. These clients generate the tokens using an app secret. From the authentication, OwinContext has `context.Authentication.User` which is used in a middleware.

**New application client**

Now I am trying to authenticate requests from a new service, which generates tokens using a certificate. However, when trying to access the Owin Context, `context.Authentication.User` is null.

I have checked the Azure Active Directory JWT payload and I can see that the Tenant, Issuer and Audience is the same as the tokens generated from other apps.

This is the service authentication I have configured:

```
    public static class AppBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureServiceAuthentication(this IAppBuilder appBuilder, AppConfig appConfig)
        {
            appBuilder.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = appConfig.AadConfig.AadTenantId,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = new []{ appConfig.AadConfig.AadApplicationId },
                        ValidIssuers = new[] { appConfig.AadConfig.AadAcceptedIssuer }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Why is `context.Authentication.User` null for the token generated by this new application? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: in `startup.cs` in `Configure` method, do you have `app.UseAuthentication();`?

Comment: Yes, that part of the configuration is set correctly as the web api is able to Authenticate other clients.

Comment: would be nice to see the registration of all of your authentication. I am thinking, dotnet default authentication handler is trying to authenticate using other authentication scheme. Eg. if you have two authentication schemes that deals with JWT on both, default scheme would pick the first one and try to authentiate on that rather than the second one, because it wont know whether this request need to authenticated by the second. Create API enpoint that require your new auth scheme and see if you can access

Comment: The web api only has a the single auth scheme so I guess there should not be any issue picking a scheme.  Additionally, this scheme is working for two other clients, however it is not able to do the same with the tokens for the new client which uses a certificate to generate them

Comment: I get this when I set my time from windows command prompt to incorrect time. Then when I corrected it, I had to reboot the computer